# Table cell shifts everything below it

Tags: html

Trying to create a table for an email. Seems like something is wrong, everything is set up the same way but once I put something different in one of the cells, the entire thing shifts. I have attached an image below to show. I am very new to this.

Here is my code:

```html
<table align="center" border="0" border-collapse="collapse" border-spacing="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" table-layout="fixed" style="max-width: 600px !important; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="25" rowspan="5" align="left" valign="top"><img src="img.jpg" style="max-width: 100px;" /></td>
      <td width="25" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft Semibold', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 12px; color: #333333;">{activity_product_short_name}</td>
      <td width="20" align="right" valign="top"></td>
      <td width="20" align="right" valign="top"></td>
      <td width="20" align="right" valign="top"></td>
      <td width="10" align="right" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft Semibold', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 12px; color: #333333;">${app_subtotal}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft Semibold', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 12px; color: #f26921;"><a href="">Click Here To Download Your Tickets</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="45" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">Ticket(s):</td>
      <td width="15" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">Date:</td>
      <td width="15" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">Time:</td>
      <td width="25" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">QTY:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">{ticket_type} ({retail_rate})</td>
      <td width="25" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">{ticket_date}</td>
      <td width="20" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">{ticket_time}</td>
      <td width="20" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">{ticket_qty}</td>
      <td width="10" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">${tt_subtotal}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">Ticket Type ($11.00)</td>
      <td width="25" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">00/00/0000</td>
      <td width="20" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">00:00PM</td>
      <td width="30" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">2</td>
      <td width="30" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Soft', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 10px; color: #71767c;">$22.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[This is what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p5OM.png)

Comment: You need to add colspan to you td's that has less td's in a single row than the one row with the most td's. The td with 100%, should have colspan="6", and remove the width 100%. If you have 6 td's in one row, the with 5 td's in another row, you'll need one of those td's to have colspan="2". And if you want these different widths, then you should go for either grid or flexbox.

Comment: Also, add some css classes to you td's, instead of those inline style.

Comment: I would add CSS but this is for email! sorry should have included that

Comment: You can still add classes in emails, just add a style section and write your classes there.

Comment: A little info about colspan can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: Oh! I thought they weren't supported by most email clients? Thanks!